# agregar una funcion php con apped() jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo este div al cual quiero inyectarle codigo html:

```
<div id="phas"></div>
```

Y este es el codigo html que le quiero agregar, pero adentro, lleva una función de php para construir los options de un select.

```
var myString = `<label>Selecciona:</label><br>
    <select class="form-control" name="attendanceSales" id="attendanceSales">
    <?php echo createSelectorOptions(); ?> 
    </select>`;
```

Y con esta función de jquery realizo el append:

```
$("#phas").append(myString);
```

El problema es que no puedo hacer la función de php que popula el select, esto es posible utilizando append en jquery?

Comment: Es imposible, para generar las opciones podrias usar Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

El código en php ponelo sin las comillas:

```
var phpCode  = <?php echo createSelectorOptions(); ?>

var myString = `<label>Selecciona:</label><br>
        <select class="form-control" name="attendanceSales" id="attendanceSales">
        `+ phpCode +`
        </select>`;
```